# Getting values from getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to get values from array:
I have this div:

```
<div class="wex">
    <p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit  amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</p>
    <p>Vestibulum volutpat, lacus a ultrices sagittis,</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Lacus a ultrices sagittis</li>
      <li>Democratis</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I use this code to get the div by class name:

```
var xx = document.getElementsByClassName("wex");
            var $boxes = $(xx);
            $container.prepend($boxes).masonry('reload');
```

This works, but with a twist. I am getting back only text from the arrau. Div, ul and P elements were not rendered.

I need to have control of the element as it is.
I will be having a hidden div with lots of elements by different class names, some of them will have same class names. I will need to find them based on criteria and display them in Masonry, however I am only getting text back.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. It is unclear what *values* means in this case (only form elements have values). Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo, it will help us to help you. If you use jQuery anyway, you can just use `$('.wex')` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName("wex")`. I also recommend to read a jQuery tutorial ( http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials ) and read the jQuery API docs: http://api.jquery.com/.

Comment: It is considered good manners to accept answers on your questions

Comment: I see your point. When I look at the source html the elements were preserved, but why the element is not being rendered correctly. It shows only text :(

Comment: Can you prepare a fiddle? If the DOM is correct but the rendering isn't, it's likely a CSS problem, not a javascript problem.

Answer (score -2):

if you using *jquery*

```
$('.classname')
```

read more about querySelectAll [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll)

Comment: I think the `$boxes` are selected correctly and that this won't help fix the problem.

Comment: This is correct, but does not answer the question. And why are you mentioning `querySelectorAll`? It's not relevant at all here.